# How to check if a given curve represents a Circle

Tags: differential-geometry

I have the following parametric curve equation

$$ y(t) = (4/5 \cos t, 1- \sin t, -3/5 \cos t) $$

and I am stuck how to find the curve equation as now it has x,y and z, while I have only dealt with x and y problems where you eliminate the parametric terms to get a Cartesian equation.

A walk through will be very helpful in finding the Cartesian equation for this one to check if it's a circle.

Comment: If you are familiar with the local theory of curves, then it suffices to show that the torsion is $0$ and the curvature is a nonzero constant.

Comment: The torsion should be zero and curvature a constant. For the latter see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Curvature.aspx . Attempt to derive curvature for r(t) = [ x(t), y(t), z(t)]. It require tangent vector, unit tangent vector and next curvature vector evaluation with cross products.Recognize special cases that you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

$$ \cos t= \frac54 x = -\frac53 z$$

$$ \cos^2t=(\frac54 x)^2=1-(1-y)^2$$

Consider:

$$x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$$

To find the curvature, you may find the center of the circle first:

$$O=\frac{y(0)+y(\pi)}2=(0,1,0)$$

$$R=\|y(t)-O\|=1$$

$$Curvature=\frac1R=1$$

Comment: wow that was so simple after you did it ! so answer should be it's a circle :)

Comment: @Geniusknight: Not necessarily. Only planar intersections of spheres are circles. The above shows that a curved space curve whose curvature you want to find lies on a unit sphere.

Comment: @Narasimham, the plane to make that intersection is $3x+4z=0$

Comment: @Narasimham yeah I figured that out since it had three parameters.

Comment: @Arashium how did you find the circle ?? Is it the relation between parametric coordinates of cos between x and z.

Comment: @Geniusknight simply here $3x=-4z$. So it is plane which crosses the sphere to make this curve and intersection of sphere and plane is always a circle if it is not empty.

Comment: @Arashium Great ! You are genius. :)